# Display Radio Buttons in HTML from Google Apps Script Function's Returned Values

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to display some radio buttons in HTML, that use whatever is returned by a function in GAS.

More specifically, I have a function which gets all of the names of the sheets in the spreadsheet. I then want each one of these sheets to display on a radio button, so the user can select a sheet name from here and send this information back to the server side.

To start, I have been trying to just get the information to display, but I haven't managed to do that.

Any help is appreciated!

```js
function getSheetNames() {
  var sheetNames = [];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNames.push(sheets[i].getName())
  }
  
  return JSON.stringify(sheetNames); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Please fill in the form below.<br><br>
    <form id="settingsForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.processForm(this)">
      <div id="output"></div>
      Sheet Name:
      <input type="text" name="sheetName"><br><br>
      Email CC:
      <input type="text" name="emailCC"><br><br>
      Send Email or Draft?:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="sendEmail" value="true" checked> Send Emails<br>
      <input type="radio" name="sendEmail" value="false"> Save to Drafts<br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form><br>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  var sheetNames = google.script.run.getSheetNames();
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.parse(sheetNames);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) unlike a normal javascript function doesn't return a value. It calls the server side function asynchronously. I.e. it calls the server side function but doesn't wait for a return or reply. It calls the function and continues with execution of remaining code.

The reason for this is so server code does not stop the loading of the page, for better user experience. However, you can use [`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) to set up a callback to client-side function once the server side function is completed. Wherein you pass a function to be called to `.withSuccessHandler()`. In your case you will do something like so:

```
<script>
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showNames).getSheetNames();
  function showNames(sheetNames){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = sheetNames;
  }
</script>
```

Note, the return from your function getSheetNames() is passed as an argument to the call back function, in this case to the `showNames()` function

Finally, to handle any failure in server code execution you can use [`google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withFailureHandler(Function)). It is always a good practice to include a function to handle failures.

**Edit:** Alternate solution using [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates). You can use scriptlets to output the value of `getSheetNames()` like so

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.parse(<?= getSheetNames() ?>);
</script>
```

This has the advantage that `getSheetNames()` execution is completed before loading the page. Just make sure that you [create an HTML Template and evaluate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String)) it before serving the web page like so:
`var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Your_HTML_File').evaluate()`